# Change picture box data depending on selected row specific cell value of datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview that displays multiple records from a table. I would like to when the user clicks on a certain row a picture box changes its picture according to a specific cell within that row. I have no idea on how to do that

Would it be something like

IF datagridview.selectedrow.cell(3) = "Bike"

picbox = ("bike.jpg")

Comment: Hi haz14! We usually like to see more code when a user submit this kind of question. It shows that you're trying to accomplish better than you might think, and also it shows that you're trying by yourself and not just letting us do all the work. Please edit your question and I'm sure somebody will be able to help you.

Comment: Have you tried anything? The 2 lines of code you posted, show you knows kind of where to go.